# Underscore Localization

Tags: localization, underscore.js

How do we do localization in UnderScore templating engine. I managed to get the localized object through require.js. Now need to pass this localized object to underscore template so that it can return me the template with the localized variable placeholders replaced with the strings passed.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small custom plugin that can be used to do the job. The plugin is available at https://github.com/paragshar/localize.

This plugin solved my problem.